# MVC route mapping: 1 URL pattern works only for exactly 1 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetAdressen",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "AdressenController", action = "GetAdressen"}
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetEinsaetze",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "EinsaetzeController", action = "GetEinsaetze"}
        );
```

In this case only /Adressen will work, and not also /Einsaetze

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetEinsaetze",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "EinsaetzeController", action = "GetEinsaetze"}
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetAdressen",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "AdressenController", action = "GetAdressen"}
        );
```

In this case only /Einsaetze will work, and not also /Adressen

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like This

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "projectName.Controllers" });
```

Comment: In my controller actions I only return a json via actionresult. I do not use a view in my mvc application.